# Wordpress Multiple Loops in Action - navigation duplicates

Tags: php, wordpress

I have already read some info about his issue on the web, but I had no serious solution.
Resources I read:
http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop#Multiple_Loops_in_Action

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/next_posts_link-not-displays-same-posts-not-next-posts-when-using-offset - Exactly the same problem.

Now here is my code in index.php:

```
<!--slider-->
<div id="featured"> 
            <?php 
                // query the posts of your custom post types
                query_posts('posts_per_page=5');
                if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<!--main body-->
    <?php 
                // query the posts of your custom post types
                query_posts('posts_per_page=5&offset=5');
                if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

When I press the next posts I get the same duplicates of the body posts.
What is the solution for this?

**EDIT:**
I have wrote new code:

```
// featured
$slider = new WP_Query(array('posts_per_page' => 5));
if ($slider->have_posts()) : while ($slider->have_posts()) : $slider->the_post();

//main:
    $p = get_query_var('paged');
                if($p >0){
                $main = new WP_Query(array('posts_per_page' => 5, 'paged'=>get_query_var('paged')));
                }else{
                $main = new WP_Query(array('posts_per_page' => 5, 'offset' => 5,'paged'=>get_query_var('paged')));
                }
                if ($main->have_posts()) : while ($main->have_posts()) : $main->the_post();
```

//navigation:

```
<div class="navigation" >
    <div class="next-posts"><div class="nextBtn2"><?php previous_posts_link(); ?></div></div>
    <div class="prev-posts"><?php next_posts_link(); ?></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is duplicated, I find it hard to read that out of your question? Something is duplicated, but it's not clear what and when.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should WP_Query for secondary loop (the featured) and use query_posts for the main body.
It works 95%
it will break on the last page because it will try to get the (very)last 5 items but those 5 will be in the offset. :(
So on the second last page you would need to hide the 'next page' pagination....

```
$featured = new WP_Query(array('posts_per_page' => 5));
if ($featured->have_posts()) : while ($featured->have_posts()) :
    $featured->the_post();

//shouldn't be needed if u use only one query_posts but it won't hurt
wp_reset_query();

$paged = get_query_var('paged');
$wanted_offset = 5;
// page zero won't need a hack
if ($paged != 0 ) {
    $post_per_page = 3;
    //$paged -1 because there is no page 1, just 0 and 2
    $offset = ($paged-1) * $post_per_page + get_query_var('posts_per_page');
} else {
    $offset = get_query_var('posts_per_page');    
}
query_posts('offset=' . $offset);
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
```

Let me know if it works for you too.

Comment: Did do know the drawback of the last page will break

Comment: It didn't break (I don't know why) but I used the infinite scroll plugin, maybe that caused it.

Comment: I think I know why, your post aren't divided by 5, so if there are 18(-5 offset) posts on the third page it still has 3 posts left

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using two instances of the WP_Query object?

```
<?php

// featured
$featured = new WP_Query(array('posts_per_page' => 5));
if ($featured->have_posts()) : while ($featured->have_posts()) : $featured->the_post();

// main body
$main = new WP_Query(array('posts_per_page' => 5, 'offset' => 5));
if ($main->have_posts()) : while ($main->have_posts()) : $main->the_post();

?>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it still doesn't work, I have edited my posts showing what I have used, to check it I suggest you visit my site and see for your self: www.gamersfleet.com

Comment: @agam360 let's clarify a few things before we move any further.. do you want to display the most recent 5 posts in the slider and skip those in the main section?

Comment: Yes I do, and I want the next page to have an offset of those 5 posts that were already shown in the slider.

Answer (score 0):

I already encounter this problem when I'm making a wordpress themes,

Actually there's many way to display the post loop, when your using

query_posts, you may need to reset the query after the loop

```
<?php

// The Query
query_posts('posts_per_page=5');   
// The 1st Loop
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    //your first set of latest posts
endwhile;  
// Reset Query
wp_reset_query();

//Second Query
query_posts(array('paged'=>$paged, 'offset'=>5));
// The 2nd Loop
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
    // your second set of posts
endwhile;
// Reset Query
    wp_reset_query();

?>
```

also you can use get post (this wp function has an offset param) for your second loop

```
<?php
global $post;
$tmp_post = $post;
$args = array( 'numberposts' => 5, 'offset'=> 1, 'category' => 1 );
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php $post = $tmp_post; ?>
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts

If you already got the post on slider, you can use this on your second loop in the body.

Hope it helps

Comment: Nope, It didn't do the trick(I've implemented the first block of code). The offset does not work. and my pages are funky.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if(is_home() && !is_paged()): ?>

?>

<?php else:
$setpo = get_option('posts_per_page');
$targ = $setpo*($paged-2)+11; ?>

<?php query_posts(array('category_name' => 'websites', 'offset' => $setpo));
endif; ?>
```